# Unexpected return value when removing a row

Tags: java, jtable, rowfilter

I am having trouble with the removal of blank lines in my JTable. When I compile it, I get a unexpected return value error. I would be grateful if someone could help fix this problem. Thanks

```
public void removeRow(int row, int column)
{
    for(int i=0;i<nextPosition;i++)
    {
        if(athTable.getModel().getValueAt(i,0).equals(""))
        {
            return row == i;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a `boolean`:

```
        return row == i;
```

When have declared your function as returning `void`.

```
public void removeRow(int row, int column)
```

This is leading to your compilation error. Replace the return with `boolean` and add a `return false;` at the end to make sure your function returns something.

Comment: Upon adding the return false at the end will that cancel the removal of the blank row?